# I'm trying to port forward on my Fritz Box

Tags: router, port-forwarding

Ok, so im trying to port forward on my fritz box 7490 to host a minecraft server, but once i've done it properly, it doesnt work, the port is not opened and the ip to join does nothing. please help, i've tried everything i could think of like deleting the port forwarding setting, factory resetting the router, factory resetting my computer, using a different computer but nothing works...

Comment: Is your ISP natting you (the IP your router is reciving is a local (10.x, 172.16.x), not the one you see on, for ex, myip.com) ? Many does, so even if you open ports on your router, without paying your ISP for a public address yowon't "exit" your ISP "LAN" with your service.

Comment: im not sure because the port forwarding i was using was working earlier but the ISP might have updated its terms and removed my public address